# Winston instance per http request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, logging, winston

Lets say I've some REST api server (maybe Express one).

When the life cycle begins (i.e someone GET 'http://foo/bar') there is some data in the `Request` object.

So let's say I've got something like this:

```
const method1 = require('some-module').method1;
app.get('/foo/bar', (req, res, next) => {
    method1();
});
```

I want a simple  way in the `some-module.js` to get a winston instance that somehow knows about all relevant data so I don't need every time to pass the request object all over my code.

The trivial solution is to pass the `method1` the object and inside do like

```
method1(req){
    winston.info('my message', {requestId: req.id}; 
}
```

But this is ugly because I need to change the signature of all my stuff just for logs.

Another option is to make everything a class that extends winston and do something like

```
app.get('/foo/bar', (req, res, next) => {
   const foo = new Foo(new winstonWrapper(req));
});
```

and than `foo.info('msg')` will call something like `winston.info('msg',{reqId:req.id})`

What an elegant way can you suggest to create a winston instance upon request and use it in other modules easily?

Comment: did you see [this](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals) ? you can create request lifetime specific objects.

Comment: @ParhamAlvani if ive a function deep in the stack, how can i know the request that initiated it?